# OpcUA The user identity token is not valid

Tags: driver, opc-ua, opc

I have a problem with the following line in code for OpcUA driver.

```
 await this._channel.OpenAsync();
```

It goes in catch and receive the following error:

Error Code: -2145386496
Error: The user identity token is not valid. Workstation.ServiceModel.Ua.ServiceResultException: The user identity token is not valid.

Security policy is none and I am trying to login without username and password.
The same combination in UaExpert is working.

Comment: Compare a Wireshark capture of UaExpert vs your application.